# Should I place frontmatter before or after maketitle?

Tags: titles, books, front-matter

When using the `book` document class, should I write

```
\maketitle
\frontmatter
% preface, toc, etc.
```

or

```
\frontmatter
\maketitle
% preface, toc, etc.
```

I see no difference in the output, but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Welcome. // Kindly have a look here or in similar books introducing LaTeX: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Book_structure

Comment: It probably depends on whether the title page should be counted. Depending on the class and setup the titlepage often resets the page number and so it makes sense to only have `\frontmatter` after the title page.

Comment: The titlepages are usually not cover pages but the innerbook title pages. These usually do not show a page number, but nevertheless the pages are counted. So `\frontmatter` should be before `\maketitle`. (This also helps to prevent the “destination with same identifier” issue often seen, when using `hyperref` and two pages with same page number.)

Comment: @cabohah Thanks for the insight

Comment: General info, for others who ind this question: As the question makes clear, this is when the `book` documentclass is used, and it may apply to some others. But some specialty classes, not necessarily part or ordinary TeX distribution, do not have `\maketitle`, and require the user to design the title page. In such a case, for an actual book, the title page is within frontmatter, so `\frontmatter` is normally the very first thing after `\begin{document}`.